# Automatically creating the desirable number of radio button questions

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

I try to make web app for creating radio button questions (like survey). The problem is defining the array of radio button options in order to call it on php page and display it in the desirable order.

In my example below, I only got one radio button of each question, and I want to display all radio buttons input on the index.html page.

This should work like this: User opens index.html, there he add the first question (button Add Question) and the proposal of answers (for example 3, which he will get by pressing the Add option button and inserting text of it). The same he should do and for the question number 2, etc...

After that, by clicking PROCEED, it should lead him to the process.php page where the survey will display radio buttons questions. But there is a mistake, please see it on the link or in the code below:

[LINK FOR TESTING](http://www.balkanex.info/atest/radio/index.html)

**index.html**

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.balkanex.info/atest/radio/process.php" method="post">
Here is the page with which you can add your new radio button questions for survey.
<input type="button" value="ADD NEW QUESTION" onclick="addradio();">
<div id="mydiv"></div> 
<br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="PROCEED"><br/> 
</form>
```

**script.js**

```
n=1;
var m = 1;
var moreradio = '<br/><input type="button" onclick="addmoreradio()" value="Add option">';
function addradio() {
        m = 1;
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "question[" + n + "]";
        textarea.rows = 1;
        textarea.cols = 60;
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = n + '. Question: ' + '<br />' + 'Que: ' + textarea.outerHTML + moreradio + '<br/><div id="opid' + n + '"' + '></div><br /><br/>';
        document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(div);
        n++;
        r = n-1;
}
function addmoreradio() {
    var radio = '<input type="text" name="tag' + r + m + '"><br/>';
    document.getElementById("opid"+r).innerHTML += radio;
    m++
}
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
$question = $_POST['question'];
$length = count($_POST['question']);
$r=1;

for($j=1; $j<$length+1; $j++) {
if($_POST['question'][$j] != "") {
    $radioarray = $_POST['tag'];
    $area = '<input type="radio" name="'.$r.'" value="'.$r.'">'.$radioarray$j$r.'<br/>';
    $bla .= $j.') '.$question[$j].'<br/>'.$area.'<br/><br/>';
    $r++;
}}

$content = $bla;
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: I dont find any mistake other than the Answer not being displayed. Is that the one you are referring to as a Mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can did a mistake on form side while naming elements. Also you did mistake on backend while iterating. You can use following;

**JS:**

```
<script>
            var m = 0;
            function addradio() {
                    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
                    textarea.name = "question[]";
                    textarea.rows = 1;
                    textarea.cols = 60;
                    var div = document.createElement("div");
                    div.innerHTML = m + '. Question: ' + '<br />' + 'Que: ' + textarea.outerHTML + '<br/><input type="button" onclick="addmoreradio(' + m + ')" value="Add option">' + '<br/><div id="opid' + m + '"' + '></div><br /><br/>';
                    document.getElementById("mydiv").appendChild(div);
                    m++;
            }
            function addmoreradio(question_id) {
                var radio = '<input type="text" name="tag' + question_id + '[]"><br/>';
                document.getElementById("opid" + question_id).innerHTML += radio;
            }
        </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.balkanex.info/atest/radio/process.php" method="post">
Here is the page with which you can add your new radio button questions for survey.
<input type="button" value="ADD NEW QUESTION" onclick="addradio();">
<div id="mydiv"></div> 
<br/> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="PROCEED"><br/> 
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$question = $_POST['question'];
$content = '';

foreach ($question as $k => $v) {
    $area = '';
    $options = $_POST["tag" . $k];
    foreach ($options as $key => $val) {
        $area .= '<input type="radio" name="tag[]" value="'. $key .'">' . $val . '<br/>';   
    }

    $content .= $k + 1 . ') ' . $question[$k].'<br/>'.$area.'<br/><br/>';   
}

echo $content;
?>
```